# JQuery Accordion not working at Bootstrap break point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a working JQuery accordian widget using the current  /  tags.  It mirrors the JQueryUI website API documentation.  I have now applied a 12col grid layout from Bootstrap to the page, and placed the accordian inside the center 10 columns.  Everything works fine for the expanding and collapsing action at/above the breakpoint of 992px.  While the div changes widths like it should I lose the ability to click on the headers and change the current open section.

JQuery is loaded before Bootstrap.

JQuery v1.9.1
Bootstrap v3.2.0

There are 8 default @media matches set with a min-width:992px, but I can't find an answer why the javascript collapsing functionality would stop working under that pixel width.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-1"></div> <!--- spanner div to adjust left cushion --->
        <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-10 sign_in_container">

    <div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
    ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
    amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
    odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
    purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
    velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
    suscipit faucibus urna.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
    Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero
    ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis
    lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>List item one</li>
      <li>List item two</li>
      <li>List item three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 4</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus
    et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
    faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia
    mauris vel est.
    </p>
    <p>
    Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus.
    Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
    inceptos himenaeos.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

</div> <!--- END div class="col-md-8 col-xs-10 sign_in_container" --->

        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-1"></div> <!--- spanner div to adjust right cushion --->
    <div> <!--- END row --->
</div> <!--- END container --->
```

Comment: what is the question and how would you expect anyone to help if we can't replicate problem without any code?

Comment: My question is what would be changing via Bootstrap at 992px versus without using Bootstrap.  I will try and put together a JSFiddle

Comment: again, how would we know what markup you used?

Comment: Hopefully this is more helpful.

Answer (score -1):

While I still could not find an answer anywhere I completed a lot of trial and error, and the final workaround or solution was to move the collapse into it's own row